# Cannot read property "style" of null

Tags: javascript, ajax, css

Good afternoon everyone!

After some researchs, I found that some people has already asked that question, but even after reading all of them, I still can't solve my problem.

In fact, I have a html document, where I include two .js files. I also have a css one to inititialize my blocks.

My goal is to display pictures to do a little parallax. I have my first pictures already defined in the html file, the other are coming with a AJAX request and an injection into the html.

So my first image to display is the one whose id is "paysage".

I include the two files a the end of the html's body.

But when I try to launch the application, the "debugger" say "Cannot read property "style" of null".

Or, just before doing the "getElementById(var)", I did a console.log to check the value of var. And var has the value "paysage". I can't solve it...

I put just here my files. I have clean the "functions.js" file, which contain some functions in order to control de mouse and the keyboard. I just put the functions involved in the issue.

Thank you in advance, and sorry for my bad english!

BBEMG.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />


    </head>

    <body onkeydown = "applyKey();" onkeyup="unApplyKey();">
        <div id="mainContainer" onclick="hClicked(event);"> 
            <div id="background">
                <img src="img/paysage-backgr.jpg" id="paysage"> 
            </div>
            <div id="Man">
                <img src="img/man-stand-up.png" id="standMan">
            </div>
            <div id="foreground">
                <img src="img/paysage-foregr.png" id="paysage-foregr">
            </div>

            <div id="text">
                <p id="blank"></p>
                <p id="cuisine-1"><em>Toaster</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="cuisine-2"><em>Coffee machine</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="cuisine-3"><em>Fridge</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="cuisine-4"><em>Microwave oven</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="cuisine-5"><em>Dishwasher</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="cuisine-6"><em>Oven</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="buanderie-1"><em>Vacuum cleaner</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="buanderie-2"><em>Iron</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="buanderie-3"><em>Washing machine</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="buanderie-4"><em>Dryer</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="buanderie-5"><em>Inverter</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="buanderie-6"><em>Meter panel</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="atelier-1"><em>Circular saw</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="atelier-2"><em>Jigsaw</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="atelier-3"><em>Screwgun</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="atelier-4"><em>Drilling</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="atelier-5"><em>Mower</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="bureau-1"><em>Photocopier</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="bureau-2"><em>Computer</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="bureau-3"><em>Flatscreen</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="bureau-4"><em>Cathodescreen</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="salon-1"><em>Halogen lamp</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="salon-2"><em>Flat TV</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="salon-3"><em>Stereo</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="sdb-1"><em>Hairdryer</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="sdb-2"><em>Heater</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="sdb-3"><em>Shaver</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="sdb-4"><em>Fluotube</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="sdb-5"><em>Toothbrush</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="chambre-1"><em>Clock</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="chambre-2"><em>Bed</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="chambre-3"><em>Ledlamp</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
                <p id="chambre-4"><em>TV cathode</em><br />x µT to y µT</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    <script src="Functions.js"></script>    
    <script src="Code.js"></script>  
    </body>

</html>
```

Functions.js

```
//structures
function Item(IDo, darkIDo, textIDo, xPoso, yPoso, isForegroundo, widtho, heighto) { //Si l'objet n'est pas connecté et est "foreground" : multiplier par 2 sa position x donnée a la base. si connecté, multiplier par 2 la position de l'objet auquel il est connecté et ajouter la largeur de l'objet auquel il est connecté
    this.ID = IDo;
    this.darkID = darkIDo;
    this.textID = textIDo;
    this.xPos = xPoso;
    this.yPos = yPoso;
    this.isForeground = isForegroundo;
    this.width = widtho;
    this.height = heighto;
}

function Man(standingIDo, leftIDo, rightIDo) {
    this.standingID = standingIDo;
    this.leftID = leftIDo; //Array
    this.rightID = rightIDo;//Array
}

function Room(relPoso, IDo, darkIDo) {
    this.relPos = relPoso;
    this.ID = IDo;
    this.darkID = darkIDo;
}

function toShow(xo, yo, IDo) {
    this.x = xo;
    this.y = yo;
    this.ID = IDo;
}

//Variables Globales ici
var START = false; //Global switch
var KEYPRESS = false; //Master du clavier sur la souris
var INPROGRESS = false; //Switch d'attente de fin de boucle move avant de redonner la main a une eventuelle nouvelle instruction clavier
var WAITINGFORSTARTING = false;
var KEEPRUNNING = false;
var WAITFORENDTIMEOUT = false;
//Parallax
var actualRoom = 0;
var calledByMoveTo = false;
var clickedOnBackground = true;
var panWidth;
var goTill;
var parallaxFactor = 2;
var actualX = 0;
var direction = 0;
var counter = 0;
var items = new Array (8);
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    switch (i){
        case 0:
        items[i] = new Array (1);
        break;
        case 1:
        items[i] = new Array (6);
        break;
        case 2:
        items[i] = new Array (6);
        break;
        case 3:
        items[i] = new Array (5);
        break;
        case 4:
        items[i] = new Array (4);
        break;
        case 5:
        items[i] = new Array (4);
        break;      
        case 6:
        items[i] = new Array (5);
        break;
        case 7:
        items[i] = new Array (4);
        break;

    }

}
var rooms = [];
var midgroundCoordx = 300;//A gerer pour centrer le bonhomme
var midgroundCoordy = 100;
var roomZLabelXDefault = 100;
var roomZLabelYDefault = 400;
//var toShow = [];
//var toHide = [];
var man;
var panWidth = 600;
var firstMove = true;
var ArrayToPaintBack = [];
var ArrayToPaintFore = [];
var ArrayToPaintText = [];
var midgroundParallax;
var oldArrayToPaintBack = [];
var oldArrayToPaintFore = [];
var oldArrayToPaintText = [];
var oldmidgroundParallax;
var manActDir = 0;
var actualImgNb = 0;
var tll = true;
//End

//Initialisation
//!!ROOMS!!
/*console.log(panWidth);*/
rooms[0] = new Room (0, "paysage", "paysage"); // pas de dark!!!!!! v0 car une variable ne peut pas commencer par un chiffre
rooms[1] = new Room (1, "cuisine", "cuisine-dark");
rooms[2] = new Room (2, "buanderie", "buanderie-dark");
rooms[3] = new Room (3, "atelier", "atelier-dark");
rooms[4] = new Room (4, "bureau", "bureau-dark");
rooms[5] = new Room (5, "salon", "salon-dark");
rooms[6] = new Room (6, "sdb", "sdb-dark");
rooms[7] = new Room (7, "chambre", "chambre-dark");
rooms[8] = new Room (8, "merci", "merci"); // pas de dark!!!!!!

//!!ITEMS!!
//declaration a revoir en fonction de la dernière version (xPos surtout)
items[0][0] = new Item("paysage-foregr","paysage-foregr","blank",40,150,true,320,92);
items[1][0] = new Item("cuisine-foregr1","cuisine-foregr1-dark","cuisine-1",120,115,true,190,245); 
items[1][1] = new Item("cuisine-foregr2","cuisine-foregr2-dark","cuisine-2",310,56,true,179,304); 
items[1][2] = new Item("blank","blank","cuisine-3",512,0,false,188,330);
items[1][3] = new Item("blank","blank","cuisine-4",700,115,false,150,70); 
items[1][4] = new Item("blank","blank","cuisine-5",700,210,false,150,110); 
items[1][5] = new Item("blank","blank","cuisine-6",1000,0,false,160,320); 
items[2][0] = new Item("buanderie-foregr","buanderie-foregr-dark","buanderie-1",-20,100,true,393,288);
items[2][1] = new Item("blank","blank","buanderie-2",310,90,false,120,70); 
items[2][2] = new Item("blank","blank","buanderie-3",460,160,false, 165,180);
items[2][3] = new Item("blank","blank","buanderie-4",625,160,false,165,180);
items[2][4] = new Item("blank","blank","buanderie-5",880,30,false,80,120);
items[2][5] = new Item("blank","blank","buanderie-6",980,30,false,200,120);
items[3][0] = new Item("atelier-foregr","atelier-foregr-dark","atelier-1",10,159,true,469,201);
items[3][1] = new Item("blank","blank","atelier-2",700,80,false,150,80);
items[3][2] = new Item("blank","blank","atelier-3",700,80,false,150,80);
items[3][3] = new Item("blank","blank","atelier-4",700,80,false,150,80);
items[3][4] = new Item("atelier-foregr2","atelier-foregr2-dark","atelier-5",800,90,true,333,270);
items[4][0] = new Item("bureau-foregr","bureau-foregr-dark","bureau-1",40,90,true,335,270);
items[4][1] = new Item("blank","blank","bureau-2",540,90,false,60,100);
items[4][2] = new Item("blank","blank","bureau-3",620,60,false,150,110);        
items[4][3] = new Item("blank","blank","bureau-4",825,80,false,115,90);     
items[5][0] = new Item("salon-foregr","salon-foregr-dark","blank",50,137,true,335,270);
items[5][1] = new Item("blank","blank","salon-1",263,50,false,62,67);
items[5][2] = new Item("blank","blank","salon-2",510,5,false,330,185);
items[5][3] = new Item("blank","blank","salon-3",860,175,false,150,30);
items[6][0] = new Item("sdb-foregr","sdb-foregr-dark","sdb-1",750,79,true,335,270);  
items[6][1] = new Item("blank","blank","sdb-2",85,200,false,240,110);
items[6][2] = new Item("blank","blank","sdb-3",405,160,false,60,20);        
items[6][3] = new Item("blank","blank","sdb-4",515,0,false,155,160);                   
items[6][4] = new Item("blank","blank","sdb-5",730,125,false,70,55);            
items[7][0] = new Item("blank","blank","chambre-1",235,185,false,400,70);
items[7][1] = new Item("blank","blank","chambre-2",340,190,false,60,35);
items[7][2] = new Item("blank","blank","chambre-3",910,0,false,60,40);
items[7][3] = new Item("blank","blank","chambre-4",1025,40,false,125,115);

//(ID, darkID, textID, x*2, y, isForeground, width, height) si isConnected = true, x = previousItemPos*2-previousItemWidth

//!!MAN!!
var rightMan = ["l1","l2","l3","l4","l5","l6"];
var leftMan = ["r1","r2","r3","r4","r5","r6"];
man = new Man ("standMan",leftMan,rightMan);
//End

function sleepFor( sleepDuration ){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* do nothing */ } 
}


function show () { //DONE
     for (var i = 0; i < ArrayToPaintBack.length; i++){
         console.log(i);
                 console.log(ArrayToPaintBack[i].ID);
                 console.log(ArrayToPaintBack.length);
        document.getElementById(ArrayToPaintBack[i].ID).style.left = ArrayToPaintBack[i].x+'px';
        document.getElementById(ArrayToPaintBack[i].ID).style.top = ArrayToPaintBack[i].y+'px';
        document.getElementById(ArrayToPaintBack[i].ID).style.display = "block";
    }

    document.getElementById(midgroundParallax.ID).style.left = midgroundParallax.x+'px';
    document.getElementById(midgroundParallax.ID).style.top = midgroundParallax.y+'px';
    document.getElementById(midgroundParallax.ID).style.display = "block";

    for (var i = 0; i < ArrayToPaintFore.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(ArrayToPaintFore[i].ID).style.left = ArrayToPaintFore[i].x+'px';
        document.getElementById(ArrayToPaintFore[i].ID).style.top = ArrayToPaintFore[i].y+'px';
        document.getElementById(ArrayToPaintFore[i].ID).style.display = "block";
    }
}

function hide () { //DONE
    for (var i = 0; i < oldArrayToPaintFore.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(oldArrayToPaintFore[i].ID).style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < oldArrayToPaintBack.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(oldArrayToPaintBack[i].ID).style.display = "none";
    }
     for (var i = 0; i < oldArrayToPaintText.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(oldArrayToPaintText[i].ID+' - Text').style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById(oldmidgroundParallax.ID).style.display = "none";
   // document.getElementById('Explanations').style.display = "none";
}

function applyKey (event){ //DONE
    if (START && !KEYPRESS){
       if (window.event) event = window.event;
       var intKeyCode = event.keyCode;
        KEYPRESS = true;
        WAITINGFORSTARTING = true;
        while (INPROGRESS);
        if (intKeyCode == 39){
            direction = 1;
            KEEPRUNNING = true;
        }
        else if (intKeyCode == 37){
            direction = -1;
            KEEPRUNNING = false;
        }

    }
}

function unApplyKey (event){ //DONE

    if (window.event) event = window.event;
    var intKeyCode = event.keyCode;
    if (intKeyCode == 39 || intKeyCode == 37){
        direction = 0;
        KEEPRUNNING = false;
        KEYPRESS = false;
    }

}
function animate (dir) { //DONE
    if (dir == manActDir) {
        if (dir == 1) {
            actualImgNb++;
            actualImgNb%=man.rightID.length;
            return man.rightID[actualImgNb];
        }
        else if (dir == -1) {
            actualImgNb++;
            actualImgNb%=man.leftID.length;
            return man.leftID[actualImgNb];
        }
        else {
            actualImgNb = 0;
            return man.standingID;
        }
    }
    else {
        manActDir = dir;
        actualImgNb = 0;
        if (dir == 1) return man.rightID[actualImgNb];
        else if (dir == -1) return man.leftID[actualImgNb];
        else return man.standingID;
    }
}

function showText () { //DONE
    var offside = 120;
    var labelWidth;
    var labelHeight;
    var itemPosX;
    var itemWidth;
    for (var i = 0; i < ArrayToPaintText.length;i++) {
        itemWidth = items[actualRoom][ArrayToPaintText[i].ID.charCodeAt(0)-48].width; //48 = '0'
        itemPosX = ArrayToPaintText[i].x;
        labelWidth =  document.getElementById(items[actualRoom][ArrayToPaintText[i].ID.charCodeAt(0)-48].textID).style.width;
        labelHeight = document.getElementById(items[actualRoom][ArrayToPaintText[i].ID.charCodeAt(0)-48].textID).style.height;
        document.getElementById(items[actualRoom][ArrayToPaintText[i].ID.charCodeAt(0)-48].textID).style.left = ((itemPosX+itemWidth/2)-(labelWidth/2)) +'px';
        document.getElementById(items[actualRoom][ArrayToPaintText[i].ID.charCodeAt(0)-48].textID).style.top = ((i==0)?120:(5+offside)) +'px';
        document.getElementById(items[actualRoom][ArrayToPaintText[i].ID.charCodeAt(0)-48].textID).style.display = "block";
        offside+=labelHeight+5;
    }
}

function move () { //Passer INPROGRESS en true a chaque debut de boucle, et le redesencre en false a chaque debut de timer //DONE ? -> A REVOIR le setTimeout
    var dir= direction;
    var accelCounter = 0;
    var time = 5;
    var goMoveTo = true;
    var GoalX = 0;
    console.log("move");
    console.log(calledByMoveTo);
    if (calledByMoveTo) GoalX = Math.floor (actualX-((goTill-(panWidth/2))/((clickedOnBackground)?1:2)));
    if (GoalX > 0 && actualRoom == 0) GoalX = -3;
    console.log(direction);
    console.log(firstMove);
    console.log(goMoveTo);
    console.log(KEEPRUNNING);
    KEEPRUNNING = true;
    while ((direction != 0 || firstMove) && goMoveTo && KEEPRUNNING) {
        console.log("while");
        if (WAITINGFORSTARTING) {WAITINGFORSTARTING = false; break;}
        if (!WAITFORENDTIMEOUT) {
        WAITFORENDTIMEOUT = true;
            //setTimeout(function() { //DEBUT DU TIMEOUT

                if (firstMove) {
                    goMoveTo = false;
                   // firstMove = false;
                    direction = 0;
                }
                else if (calledByMoveTo){
                    if (dir ==1){
                        if (actualX <= GoalX) goMoveTo = false;
                    }
                    else if (dir == -1) {
                        if (actualX >= GoalX) goMoveTo = false;
                    }
                }
                dir = direction;
                counter++;
                counter=counter%10;
                accelCounter++;
                accelCounter%=(100*(6-time));
                actualX+=(-(2*direction));

                if (actualX+((actualRoom ==0)?600:1200) <= panWidth/2) {
                    if (actualRoom < rooms.length-2) {
                        GoalX+=((actualRoom == 0)?600:1200);
                        actualRoom++;
                        actualX = panWidth/2;
                    }
                    else actualX-=(-(2*dir));
                }
                else if (actualX > panWidth/2) {
                    if (actualRoom > 0) {
                        actualRoom--;
                        actualX = (panWidth/2)-((actualRoom == 0)?600:1200);
                        GoalX-=((actualRoom==0)?600:1200);
                    }
                    else actualX-=(-(2*dir));
                }

                ArrayToPaintBack = [];
                var a = new toShow(actualX,0,rooms[actualRoom].ID);
                ArrayToPaintBack.push(a);
                if (actualRoom > 0) ArrayToPaintBack.push(actualX-(actualRoom==1)?600:1200,0, rooms[actualRoom-1].darkID);
                if (actualRoom < rooms.length-1) ArrayToPaintBack.push (actualX+((actualRoom==0)?600:1200),0, rooms[actualRoom+1].darkID);
console.log("length:" + ArrayToPaintBack.length);
                ArrayToPaintFore = [];
                if (actualRoom > 0) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < items[actualRoom-1].length; i++) {
                        if (items[actualRoom-1][i].isForeground) {
                            var b = new toShow (items[actualRoom-1][i].xPos+((actualX-((actualRoom==0)?600:1200))*((items[actualRoom-1][i].isForeground)?parallaxFactor:1)), items[actualRoom-1][i].yPos, items[actualRoom-1][i].darkID);
                            ArrayToPaintFore.push(b);
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < items[actualRoom].length;i++) {
                    console.log(actualRoom);
                                        console.log(i);
                    if (items[actualRoom][i].isForeground) ArrayToPaintFore.push(items[actualRoom][i].xPos+(actualX*((items[actualRoom][i].isForeground)?parallaxFactor:1)), items[actualRoom][i].yPos, items[actualRoom][i].ID);

                    if((items[actualRoom][i].xPos+(actualX*((items[actualRoom][i].isForeground)?parallaxFactor:1)) <= panWidth/2) && (items[actualRoom][i].xPos+(actualX*((items[actualRoom][i].isForeground)?parallaxFactor:1))+items[actualRoom][i].width >= panWidth/2)){
                        var c = new toShow (items[actualRoom][i].xPos+(actualX*((items[actualRoom][i].isForeground)?parallaxFactor:1)), items[actualRoom][i].yPos, i);
                        ArrayToPaintText.push(c);
                    }
                }

                if (actualRoom < rooms.length-1) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < items[actualRoom+1].length; i++) {
                        if (items[actualRoom+1][i].isForeground){
                            ArrayToPaintFore.push(items[actualRoom+1][i].xPos+((actualX+((actualRoom == 0)?600:1200))*((items[actualRoom+1][i].isForeground)?parallaxFactor:1)), items[actualRoom+1][i].yPos,items[actualRoom+1][i].ID);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (counter == 0||firstMove){
                    alert("coucou"); // ne passe jamais ici
                    midgroundParallax = new toShow (midgroundCoordx, midgroundCoordy, animate(dir));
                    firstMove=false;
                }

                if (accelCounter == 0) if (time >1 ) time--;
                if (actualRoom == 0) displayExplanation (roomZLabelXDefault+(actualX*parallaxFactor), roomZLabelYDefault);
                if (!tll)   hide();
                show();
                showText();
                oldArrayToPaintBack = ArrayToPaintBack;
                oldArrayToPaintFore = ArrayToPaintFore;
                oldArrayToPaintText = ArrayToPaintText;
                oldmidgroundParallax = midgroundParallax;
                INPROGRESS = false;
                WAITFORENDTIMEOUT = false;
                tll = false;
                sleepFor (time);
            //}, time); //FIN DU TIMEOUT
        }
    }
    console.log("OutOfWhile");
    //while (WAITFORENDTIMEOUT){};
    console.log("20");
    INPROGRESS = false;
    document.getElementById(midgroundParallax.ID).style.display = 'none';
    console.log("21");
    midgroundParallax = new toShow (midgroundCoordx, midgroundCoordy, animate(0));
    console.log("22");
    document.getElementById(midgroundParallax.ID).style.left = midgroundParallax.x+'px';
    console.log("23");
    document.getElementById(midgroundParallax.ID).style.top = midgroundParallax.y+'px';
    console.log("24");
    document.getElementById(midgroundParallax.ID).style.display = 'block';
    calledByMoveTo = false;
    console.log("25");
}
```

code.js

```
var xhr = null;
var hasbeenreceived = 0;
console.log("0");
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("1");
}

else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    console.log("2");
}
else {
    alert("Votre navigateur n'est pas compatible avec la technologie AJAX. Cette technologie est utilisée afin de faire fonctionner cette application. Veuillez mettre à jour votre navigateur ou en choisir un autre.");
}





var i = 0;
if (xhr) {
    var target;
    console.log("3");
     xhr.open ("GET", "Man.txt", true);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //alert ("State changed for " + xhr.readyState);
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            console.log("4");
            if (i == 0) {
                target = document.getElementById("Man");
                console.log("5");
            } else if (i == 1) {
                target = document.getElementById("background");
                console.log("6");
            } else if (i == 2) {
                target = document.getElementById("foreground");
                console.log("7");
            }
            console.log("8");
            var toPut = xhr.responseText;
            target.innerHTML = toPut;
            hasbeenreceived = 1;
            i++;
            if (i <= 2) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    xhr.open ("GET", "background.txt", true);
                    console.log("9");
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    xhr.open ("GET", "foreground.txt", true);
                    console.log("10");
                }
            }
            console.log("11");
        } else {
             document.getElementById("Afficheur").innerHTML ("readyState : " + xhr.readyState + " - status : " + status + "<br>");
             alert ("Change in AFFICHEUR");
        }
    }
    START = true;
    console.log("12");
    move();
    firstMove = false;
} //Fin du programme
```

main.css

```
#paysage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your code has a function call in it which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, when i try to run his code I get an error complaining about the missing function. Not the error described in his title

Comment: @Ajenkins Maybe you structured his script a different way

Comment: The debugger tells you which line (of your code) generated the error.  Tell us what that line is.  It's most probably one of the lines where you ask document.getElementById( ... .ID).style. ... but I don't know which

Comment: @TheProHands if you search his code the function does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There're many other problems in the code, but the error happened because such elements by ID as `"cuisine"`, `"chambre"` and etc, doesn't exist in your HTML page, so `document.getElementById(...)` returns `undefined`. You forgot specifying the element ID including the "-[number]", for example, here:

```
document.getElementById(ArrayToPaintBack[i].ID)
```

I think that'd solve the error here (I found this part in a `for` loop):

```
document.getElementById(ArrayToPaintBack[i].ID + "-" + (i + 1))
// i.e, "cuisine-1"
```

You can check your HTML page to confirm, there are elements with `"id"` like `cuisine-1`, etc, but in your script you only specify the first part of these classes. You should include a sequential number with a hiphen.